# How to install 'dfu-util'

Tags: macos, config, dfu

I've been trying to install dfu-util on my [Mac OS X v10.7.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Lion) (Lion). I follow the instructions on:

> https://forum.seeedstudio.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=1364

Everything seems to be working properly, but when I run the command:

```
./configure --libdir=/opt/local/lib --includedir=/opt/local/include
```

This error appears:

> ```
> ./configure: line 3770: syntax error near unexpected token `USB,'
> ./configure: line 3770: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(USB, libusb >= 0.1.4,,'
> ```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should install pkgconfig (then rerun `autogen.sh` before `./configure`).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to install DFU-UTIL in 2015 using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable `brew`) on OS X, you'll find that the *dfu-util.gnumonks.org* site has been down since November of 2014. Here's the workaround...

Since Homebrew is looking for the 0.7 release and the *gnumonks.org* fellows have put up a mirror on [SourceForge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge), you can download "dfu-util-0.7.tar.gz" from *http://dfu-util.sourceforge.net/releases/* and place it into your */Library/Caches/Homebrew* directory. Then, executing the command "brew install dfu-util" will work as expected!